# google colab, can't pickle my defaultdict - recursionerror

Tags: python, pickle, google-colaboratory, defaultdict

I am using google colab.  I have done the exact thing I am trying to do many times, so I don't know why it's not working now.

All i do is make a dictionary with around 1000 keys, and every value is a list of 4 strings.
I've confirmed the dictionary is exactly what I think it is.

I am using joblib.  I also tried just, pickle.dump.

`dump(mydict,'/content/gdrive/My Drive/mydict.joblib')`

It results in:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
RecursionError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-5-7edb860e5e4b> in <module>()
----> 1 dump(newdict,'/content/gdrive/My Drive/refs2019.joblib')

74 frames
... (skipped 134 stack entries. Use sys.last_value and sys.last_traceback to investigate further.) ...
... last 203 frames repeated, from the frame below ...

/usr/lib/python3.6/pickle.py in save(self, obj, save_persistent_id)
    519 
    520         # Save the reduce() output and finally memoize the object
--> 521         self.save_reduce(obj=obj, *rv)
    522 
    523     def persistent_id(self, obj):

RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded in comparison
```

I've tried it several times.  I tried it on different runtimes.  I checked that my google drive isn't full, it isn't.  I even created a list of comparable size and pickled it in the same runtime.  It worked fine.

Any advice?  I am not sure what to do.  Maybe just try it again later?  I'd be a bit sad if that's the case.

Answer (score 1):

Alright, it drove me nuts but I eventually figured it out.
I had a defaultdict(list) of what I thought were strings.

But actually they were some sort of beautiful soup objects that result from calling table.string.

A bit misleading.  And apparently it completely screws up any sort of pickling.  Also screwed up my attempt at json dumps, too.

I fixed it by explicitly casting them to strings, and now it will actually pickle.

Comment: I believe you can also use `.text` directly instead of `.string` and then casting with `str()`.